# Assigning Value to Json data in the loop is replacing the old data

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

There is a array to which the Json variable is passed as parameter. During the loop the json ariable is added with extra sub variables which is assigned new values on every looping.

```
var getDataArrList = function (arrList, itemData, forControlMode) {  
        $(arrList).each(function (index, value) {
            itemData.itemCaption = value;
            itemData.itemValue = value.toLowerCase();
            returnArrSet.push({ name: value, value: itemData })
        })
    }
```

where arrList is **arrList = ["Open", "Released"];** and itemData is the Json Variable.

Itemdata will already have two data. itemData.screenTitle and itemData.otherDetails. Which remains same for both the array elements of  **arrList**

On first loop cylce the itemData will have data like

```
itemData = { 
         itemData.screenTitle = 'some value',
         itemData.otherDetails = 'some details' 
         itemData.itemCaption = "Caption1",  
         itemData.itemValue = "Items list1"  
         }
```

These values are assigned and pushed like `returnArrSet.push({ name: value, value: itemData })`

On Second loop cylce the itemData should have data like

```
itemData = { 
         itemData.screenTitle = 'some value',
         itemData.otherDetails = 'some details' 
         itemData.itemCaption = "Caption 2",  
         itemData.itemValue = "Items list 2"  
         }
```

In **returnArrSet** second loop element should have fresh value  Caption 2 and Items list 2 but the loop is assigning the value to second element as well as **FIRST ELEMENT** in the **returnArrSet**. Please help me in find alternative solutions

Answer (score 1):

`itemData` is a reference to an object, meaning all the references point to the same set of data. This is easily solvable by creating a new object for the array.

```
var getDataArrList = function (arrList, itemData, forControlMode) {  
    $(arrList).each(function (index, value) {
        returnArrSet.push({ name: value, 
       value: {
                screenTitle : itemData.screenTitle,
                otherDetails : itemData.otherDetails,
                itemCaption : value,
                itemValue : value.toLowerCase()
              }
    })
    })
}
```

Comment: I've run into this myself.. references can be a blessing and a curse.